# Random Custom Post Type Titles

Tags: custom-post-types, get-the-title

So i found the code below from another question on here, it displays a list of titles from a custom post type, my question is, How do i get the list to randomize?

```
      <?php
 $queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=announcements&posts_per_page=5' );
 // The Loop!if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
?>
<ul>
<?php
while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
    $queryObject->the_post();
    ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_Query` has an `orderby` property which can be set to `rand`. If you change your query string to `'post_type=announcements&posts_per_page=5&orderby=rand'` you should be good to go. You might want to take the time to read through [the whole documentation for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), just so you're familiar with its capabilities.